# Do not rotatel label with marker - Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a simple way to make label **not** move with the marker rotation?

Here is example of marker at 0° rotation with label right above it:

[image: label at right position]

But when I rotate the marker, label rotates (moves) with it like on this example:

[image: label at wrong position]

I would like to prevent it and make label stay right above marker all the time. Here is a function that creates the markers:

```
var path = 'M 4.2333332,0.26458333 C 3.6453105,0.26458333 3.6452221,1.5875001 3.6452221,1.5875001 V 3.4018596 L 0.26458331,5.3665975 V 6.2363118 L 3.6452221,5.4808025 V 6.6900309 L 2.4695001,7.6729167 V 8.2020834 L 3.8997703,7.9261312 C 3.9310853,8.0342939 4.0106398,8.1255601 4.1223122,8.1638429 4.3053607,8.2271499 4.5031497,8.1254389 4.5638959,7.9380168 4.5652259,7.9339868 4.5647152,7.9296768 4.5658959,7.9256158 L 5.9971665,8.2010511 V 7.6723999 L 4.8214444,6.6895142 V 5.479769 L 8.2020834,6.2363118 V 5.3665975 L 4.8214444,3.4018596 V 1.5875001 C 4.8214444,1.5875001 4.8213561,0.26458333 4.2333332,0.26458333 Z';
function createMarker(pos, hdg, icao) {
var icon = {
    path: path,
    fillColor: 'white',
    fillOpacity: 1,
    scale: 3,
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeWeight: 2,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(3.97, 3.98),
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(3.97, -3),
    rotation: hdg
};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    icon: icon,
    label: icao
});
return marker;
}
```

I know when I set the `labelOrigin` to place the label in middle of the marker it does not move, but in this case the label obvoiusly intersects the marker and is hard to read.

Comment: Rather than using the built in label for the marker, you can make the label a separate thing from the marker (like an [InfoBox](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/infobox), then offset it from the marker by some distance (either in pixels or meters)

Comment: Tried using that InfoBox lib but it freezes the whole map wherever I try placing the Infobox. So far can't get it to work. Is it possibile it only supports 1 infobox at a time, cause that would be a problem for my case. I followed this example: https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/infobox/examples/infobox-label.html

Comment: There can be multiple infoboxes on the map.  My guess is you are doing something wrong, but that is a different question.

Comment: In Chrome console it throws: `Uncaught TypeError: a.lng is not a function` when I try to add infobox and each time I try to move map so map appears frozen.

Comment: The simplest way seems to be just to add invisible marker with label on top of existing one that wont rotate.

Comment: That would work too.